# Convert Any to Integer in Scala?

Tags: scala, type-conversion

How do I convert an Any to an Integer?

Specifically, I have a function that returns Any, and in one situation I know it will return a number of type Any, and I need that number to be converted to type Integer so I can use it in another function.

Comment: `x.asInstanceOf[Int]` but if you're handling data of type `Any` then something has gone terribly wrong.

Comment: I have a function that searches through a map[String, Any], where Any could be one of multiple different data types, and based on the string, returns type Any. In this case I am having it search for a number, but is returned as type Any.

Comment: @jwvh that seemed to work! Put it in an answer so I can accept.

Comment: Having such `Any` map is rarely a good idea

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your function is likely designed very poorly. 99% of the time there is a better way, then just returning `Any` from an API entry point.

If you insist on having to deal with `Any`, a safe way to convert it to an int would be something like this:

```
def toInt(x: Any): Option[Int] = x match {
  case i: Int => Some(i)
  case _ => None
}
```